# Error in simulating OpenModelica example using FMPy

Tags: python, openmodelica

I'm trying to simulate Modelica.Fluid.Examples.BranchingDynamicPipes using FMPy.
This error shows up ever time I try:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pipe_modelica.py", line 18, in <module>
    result = simulate_fmu(fmu, stop_time = 3)
  File "C:\Users\radicalroar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\fmpy\simulation.py", line 494, in simulate_fmu
    model_description = read_model_description(filename, validate=validate)
  File "C:\Users\radicalroar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\fmpy\model_description.py", line 818, in read_model_description
    raise Exception('The unit "%s" of variable "%s" (line %s) is not defined.' % (unit, variable.name, variable.sourceline))
Exception: The unit "kg/s" of variable "pipe1.flowModel.m_flows[1]" (line 236) is not defined.
```

(The exception seems to be about the dynamic pipe component which is defined in a system library class which I can't edit.)
Any help on how to simulate the FMU would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the FMI export in OpenModelica. The problem has been solved recently. Please try again with the latest nightly build or wait for the upcoming v1.16 release.

These are the related OpenModelica contributions:

- https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/pull/896
- https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/pull/975

Comment: Any corroboration (link or something)?